# Declarar tipo de dato estructura

Tags: c, estructuras

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct estudiante {
    int ced;
    int aniocarrera;
    char grupo;
};
estudiante e; //<-error: unknown type name 'estudiante'
int I;
void ingresar(estudiante* e) {
    printf(" Ingresar la cedula ");
    scanf("%d",&e.ced);
    printf("Ingresar el año de la carrera ");
    scanf("%d",&e.aniocarrera);
    printf("Ingrese el grupo ");
    scanf("%c",&e.grupo);
}

void mostrar(estudiante alum) {
    printf("La cedula es ");
    printf("%d", e.ced);
    printf("\r\n");
    printf("El año de la carrera es ");
    printf("%d", e.aniocarrera);
    printf("\r\n");
    printf("El grupo es ");
    printf("%c", e.grupo);
    printf("\r\n");
}

int main() {
    ingresar(e);
    mostrar(e);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Tira los siguientes errores:

> error: unknown type name 'estudiante'

Comment: Alejandro ¿Cual es la pregunta?, revisa [ask] por favor, saludos.

Comment: Si declaras de tipo char la variable grupo dentro de la estructura estudiantes, no la puedes utilizar con %d, eso es para datos enteros, deberías usar %c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La corrección estaba parcialmente bien, corregías el acceso a los elementos de la estructura, pero el tipo de dato estructura se seguía sin definir.
Hay que definir el tipo de dato estructura, que es lo
PD: Limpiar el buffer en después del segundo scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct estudiante {
    int ced;
    int aniocarrera;
    char grupo;
};
typedef struct estudiante estudiante;
estudiante e;
void ingresar(estudiante* e) {
    printf("Ingresar la cedula: ");
    scanf("%d",&e->ced);
    printf("Ingresar el a%co de la carrera: ",164);
    scanf("%d",&e->aniocarrera);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese el grupo: ");
    scanf("%c",&e->grupo);
}

void mostrar(estudiante e) {
    printf("\n\nLa cedula es: %d",e.ced);
    printf("\nEl a%co de la carrera es: %d",164,e.aniocarrera);
    printf("\nEl grupo es: %c",e.grupo);
}

int main() {
    ingresar(&e);
    mostrar(e); 
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La corrección de tu código seria así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct estudiante {
    int ced;
    int aniocarrera;
    char grupo;
}e;

void ingresar(struct estudiante* e) {
    printf("Ingresar la cedula: ");
    scanf("%d",&e->ced);
    printf("Ingresar el a%co de la carrera: ",164);
    scanf("%d",&e->aniocarrera);
    printf("Ingrese el grupo: ");
    scanf("%s",&e->grupo);
}

void mostrar(struct estudiante e) {
    printf("\n\nLa cedula es: %d",e.ced);
    printf("\nEl a%co de la carrera es: %d",164,e.aniocarrera);
    printf("\nEl grupo es: %c",e.grupo);
}

int main() {
    ingresar(&e);
    mostrar(e); 
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Como te dije en el comentario de arriba si utilizar una variable tipo char no puedes utilizar %d.

La función void ingresar(estudiante* e) le estas pasando un puntero, por tanto en la asignación de datos debes utilizar la flecha -> y no el punto .

Comment: Tu corrección es parcial. Sigue habiendo errores de compilación.

Comment: A mi me funciona bien, donde esta los errores de compilación?

Comment: Compila en C, no en C++. Tu solución no es válida en C

Comment: Ahora si compila en C, fallo mio.

Comment: Ahora ya si puede pasar por una correcta ;)